# Robot Framework string padding

Tags: python, robotframework

Looking for a way to have some more nice aligned output on Robot Framework (set test message or log). Here's the example on how I done it on python:

```
print "%-12s" % "received:", "%-5s" % 1323
print "%-12s" % "sent:", "%-5s" % 123
```

Output:

```
received:    1323 
sent:        123
```

Is it possible to do the same on Robot Framework?

Currently my code is:

```
Set Test Message      received: ${rx}\nsent: ${tx}
```

and my output is like this (2 examples with different values):

```
received: 847383
sent: 9511

received: 4814
sent: 9511111
```

My expected output should be

```
received: 847383
sent:     9511

received: 4814
sent:     9511111
```

or

```
received:  847383
sent:        9511

received:    4814
sent:     9511111
```

Comment: It's possible to do exactly that (ie: write a function that prints things with padding), but I don't think that's what you're really asking. Can you give a minimal example of a test, and the output that you want it to generate? Are you wanting to do this with robot log statements, or is it acceptable to write a python-based keyword that prints to the screen? Do you want the information to show up in the log too, or just the screen?

Comment: Updated the code and example outputs. I'm looking for a way to do it native in RF

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you want. Are you wanting this to appear formatted this way in log.html, only on the console, or both? What you see in the console and what you see in the log are two different formats (ascii vs html)

Comment: I need it only in console. I know there's different fonts in log(html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to run a short snippet of python code to format the string. Here's a keyword that does that for you:

```
*** Keywords ***
Record sent and received
    [Arguments]    ${sent}    ${received}
    ${message}=    Evaluate    
    ...    "%-12s %s\\n%-12s %s\\n" % ('received:', '${received}', 'sent:', '${sent}')
    set test message    ${message}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using Evaluate and use [Format String keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Format%20String) in Robot Framework's String library instead:

```
    ${msg}=    Format String    {: >10} {: >12}\n{: >10} {: >12}    Received:  ${rx}  Sent:  ${tx}
    Set Test Message      ${msg}
```

Format string's first parameter is the format, here `{: >10} {: >12}\n{: >10} {: >12}`.

The remaining four parameters (literal string "Received:", variable rx, literal string "Sent:" and variable tx)  are the values that are inserted in the placeholders in their order, marked with the curly braces, in the template. *The template is formatted using [Python's format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)* as the documentation states.

The following example would set the `msg` variable to something like:

```
 Received:        69493
     Sent:  12312958234
```

Check the linked documentation for more complex examples and make sure that you're using recent enough Robot Framework version (3.1 or newer) which include the keyword.